# Investigating functions - Lagranges mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, functions

With the aid of Lagrange's formula prove the inequality :

$ \frac{a-b}{a} \leq ln \frac{a}{b} \leq \frac{a-b}{b}$

for the condition $ 0 < b \leq a$

Please guide how to proceed for this..

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly straightforward. For $a\ne b$, apply the theorem to $f(x)=\ln x$ on the interval $[b,a]$.

See below for more.

One obtains ${\ln a-\ln b\over a-b}={1\over c}$ for some $c\in(b,a)$. Note ${1\over a}<{1\over c}<{1\over b}$. Use this, a certain property of the logarithmic function,  and a bit of algebra.

I'll leave the case when $a=b$ to you.

Comment: +1 because you have been faster, but the last inequality is wrong.

Comment: @user01123581321345589144... Thanks. I was still thinking that $a<b$...

Comment: this is obviously the reason, I have pointed out for clarity only :D

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\log a - \log b}{a - b} = \frac{1}{c},\qquad c \in (b,a).$$ the rest easily follows from the obvious inequalities $$\frac{1}{a} < \frac{1}{c} < \frac{1}{b}$$